# collect_list keeping order (sql/spark scala)

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a table like this :

```
Clients   City   Timestamp
1         NY        0
1         WDC       10
1         NY        11    
2         NY        20
2         WDC       15
```

What I want as an output is to collect all the cities **based on the timestamp** (each timestamp has a unique city per user). But **without displaying the timestamp**. The final list must only contains the cities in order. So, for that example, it gives something like this :

```
Clients   my_list   Timestamp
1         NY - WDC - NY
2         WDC - NY
```

Maybe, I should generate a list using timestamp. Then remove the timestamp in this list. I don't know...

I am using spark sql with scala. So,I tried to use collect_list in both sql or in scala but it seems that we lose the ordering after using it.

Can you help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: For Client 2, I think you have posted the city order wrong. You want it by the increasing order of the timestamp, right @salamanka44

Comment: @apnith yes of course. I want the increasing order of the timestamp. I just corrected my error. Sorry for the error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# below can be helpful for you to achieve your target
val input_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("1","NY","0"),("1","WDC","10"),("1","NY","11"),("2","NY","20"),("2","WDC","15")))
val input_df = input_rdd.toDF("clients","city","Timestamp")
val winspec1 = Window.partitionBy($"clients").orderBy($"Timestamp")
val input_df1 = input_df.withColumn("collect", collect_list($"city").over(winspec1))
input_df1.show
Output:
+-------+----+---------+-------------+
|clients|city|Timestamp|      collect|
+-------+----+---------+-------------+
|      1|  NY|        0|         [NY]|
|      1| WDC|       10|    [NY, WDC]|
|      1|  NY|       11|[NY, WDC, NY]|
|      2| WDC|       15|        [WDC]|
|      2|  NY|       20|    [WDC, NY]|
+-------+----+---------+-------------+

val winspec2 = Window.partitionBy($"clients").orderBy($"Timestamp".desc)
input_df1.withColumn("number", row_number().over(winspec2)).filter($"number" === 1).drop($"number").drop($"Timestamp").drop($"city").show
Output:
+-------+-------------+
|clients|      collect|
+-------+-------------+
|      1|[NY, WDC, NY]|
|      2|    [WDC, NY]|
```

Answer (score 3):

I would simply do the below:

```
val a = Seq((1,"NY",0),(1,"WDC",10),(1,"NY",11),(2,"NY",20),(2,"WDC",15))
    .toDF("client", "city", "timestamp")

val w = Window.partitionBy($"client").orderBy($"timestamp")
val b = a.withColumn("sorted_list", collect_list($"city").over(w))
```

Here I used `Window` to partiton over client and ordered on timestamp
At this point you have a dataframe like this:

```
+------+----+---------+-------------+
|client|city|timestamp|sorted_list  |
+------+----+---------+-------------+
|1     |NY  |0        |[NY]         |
|1     |WDC |10       |[NY, WDC]    |
|1     |NY  |11       |[NY, WDC, NY]|
|2     |WDC |15       |[WDC]        |
|2     |NY  |20       |[WDC, NY]    |
+------+----+---------+-------------+
```

Here, you created the new column sorted_list has ordered list of values, sorted by timestamp, but you have duplicated rows per client. To remove the duplicated ones, `groupBy` client and keep the max value in for each group:

```
val c = b
        .groupBy($"client")
        .agg(max($"sorted_list").alias("sorted_timestamp"))
.show(false)

+------+----------------+
|client|sorted_timestamp|
+------+----------------+
|1     |[NY, WDC, NY]   |
|2     |[WDC, NY]       |
+------+----------------+
```

Comment: @salamaka44 If the answer solved your problem, please do accept it

Comment: I think you didn't understand well my message. What I want as a final output is the sorted list of cities (BASES on timestamp). Not the sorted timestamp (at the final output, I won't show timestamps...). I hope it's clearer now for you ?

Comment: @salamanka44 What I had posted is sufficient to arrive at the answer you need if you read/understand the solution. I have updated the `collect_list` here. The rest remains the same. I hope you got the concept. Let me know if you still find any difficulties

Answer (score 0):

Since spark 2.4, you can apply your first idea of creating an object with timestamp and city, collect those objects as list, sort the list and then drop timestamp for each object in the list:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_sort, col, collect_list, struct}

val result = inputDf.groupBy("Clients")
  .agg(
    array_sort(
      collect_list(
        struct(col("Timestamp"), col("City"))
      )
    ).getField("City").as("Cities")
  )
```

With the following `inputDf` dataframe:

```
+------+----+---------+
|Client|City|Timestamp|
+------+----+---------+
|1     |NY  |0        |
|1     |WDC |10       |
|1     |NY  |11       |
|2     |NY  |20       |
|2     |WDC |15       |
+------+----+---------+
```

You will get the following `result` dataframe:

```
+------+-------------+
|Client|Cities       |
+------+-------------+
|1     |[NY, WDC, NY]|
|2     |[WDC, NY]    |
+------+-------------+
```

Using this method, you will only shuffle your input dataframe once.